# How to know when a destructor is called? in c++

Tags: c++, class, destructor

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Point {
private:
int x;
int y;
static int numCreatedObjects;
public:
Point() :x(0), y(0) {
    numCreatedObjects++;
}
Point(int _x, int _y) {
    x = _x;
    y = _y;
    numCreatedObjects++;
}
~Point() {
    cout << "Destructed..." << endl;
}
void setXY(int _x, int _y) {
    this->x= _x;
    this->y = _y;
}

int getX() const { return x; }
int getY() const { return y; }

Point operator+(Point& pt2) {
    Point result(this->x + pt2.x, this->y + pt2.y);
   return result;
}

Point& operator = (Point& pt) {
    this->x = pt.x;
    this->y = pt.y;
}

static int getNumCreatedObject() { return numCreatedObjects; }
friend void print(const Point& pt);
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& cout, Point& pt);
friend class SpyPoint;
};

int Point::numCreatedObjects = 0;

void print(const Point& pt) {
cout << pt.x << "," << pt.y << endl;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& cout, Point& pt) {
cout << pt.x << "," << pt.y;
return cout;
}

class SpyPoint{
public:
void hack_point_info(const Point& pt) {
    cout << "Hacked by SpyPoint" << endl;
    cout <<"x: "<<pt.x <<endl<<"y: "<<pt.y << endl;
    cout << "numCreatedObj:" << pt.getNumCreatedObject() << endl;
}
};

int main() {
Point pt1(1, 2);
cout << "pt1 : ";
print(pt1);
cout << endl;

Point* pPt1 = &pt1;
cout << "pt1 : ";
cout << pPt1->getX() << ", " << pPt1->getY() << endl;
cout << "pt1 : ";
cout << pPt1->getX() << ", " << pPt1->getY() << endl;
cout << endl;

Point* pPt2 = new Point(10, 20);
cout << "pt2 : ";
cout << pPt2->getX() << ", " << pPt2->getY() << endl;
cout << endl;

delete pPt2;

cout << "pt1 NumCreatedObject : ";
cout << pt1.getNumCreatedObject() << endl;



Point pt2(10, 20);
Point pt3(30, 40);
Point pt4 = pt2 + pt3;
cout << "pt2 : ";
cout << pt2 << endl;
cout << "pt3 : ";
cout << pt3 << endl;
cout << "pt4 : ";
cout << pt4 << endl;

cout << "pt1 NumCreatedObject : ";
cout << pt1.getNumCreatedObject() << endl << endl;

Point* ptAry = new Point[5];
cout << "pt2 NumCreatedObject : ";
cout << pt2.getNumCreatedObject() << endl;
cout << endl;

delete[] ptAry;
cout << endl;

SpyPoint spy;
cout << "pt1 info" << endl;
spy.hack_point_info(pt1);
cout << endl;

cout << "pt4 info" << endl;
spy.hack_point_info(pt4);
cout << endl;
return 0;
}
```

[image]

I don't know why the yellow underlined part prints out. I understand that the destructor is called when returning, unless it is dynamically allocated.

I guess pt1 is going to disappear, but I don't know why.

Also, I would like to know if there is a method that can be forcibly destroyed even if it is not dynamically allocated.

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: Attach a debugger, put a breakpoint in the destructor, look at stack trace.

Comment: Your `operator+` creates a new temporary `Point`, returns a copy of it and then destroys the temporary. What are you confused about?

Comment: C++ does not use garbage collection, instead the destruction of objects is very deterministic.  Because of that reliable behavior, the [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) technique works well.  Objects are destructed at the end of their scope.  Unmanaged memory, such as with raw pointers, has to be destructed explicitly (which is why it is recommended never to have raw pointers in modern C++ code).

Comment: I'm guessing the confusion is because you think the yellow highlighted output refers to `pt1`. It doesn't, it refers to `result` declared in operator+.

Comment: Minor correction:  "which is why it is recommended never to have raw **owning** pointers in modern C++ code".  It's fine to have a non-owning pointer parameter, which may be nullptr.  (If it ought not be nullptr, then a const-reference parameter or reference parameter is a better alternative.)

Comment: Return by copy may create and delete an instance. To prevent this, return by reference. C++17 improved on this very topic.